# NSOutputStream not calling delegate's NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable

Tags: ios, sockets, nsoutputstream

I have implemented socket by using input and output streams. The external architecture takes care of sending one request at a time to write.

However if any request does not return no `HasBytesAvailable` I need to remove that request from queue and inform about request timeout.

For all other requests, I am able to send/receive data correctly, but if any one of the request time outs then after that `HasSpaceAvailable` never gets called.

My code is as follows :

@implementation CCCommandSocket

@synthesize connectionTimeoutTimer;
@synthesize requestTimeoutTimer;

/*
 * init
 *
 * @params
 * ipAddress :ip address of camera socket
 * portNumber :port address of camera socket
 *
 * @return
 * Object of type Socket, which will send connection request to ipAddress,portNumber
 *
 */
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        ip   = @"192.168.42.1";
        port = 7878;

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(connectToCamera) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    bytesReceivedCondition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
    requestCompletedCondition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
    requestReadyToProcess = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
    isBytesReceived = false;
    isRequestCompleted = false;
    isRequestReadyToProcess = false;
    responseString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    openBracesCount = 0;

    mutex = [[NSLock alloc] init];
}
return self;
```

}

## pragma mark-

## pragma establish socket communication.

/*
 * connectToCamera
 *
 */
- (void) connectToCamera
{
    NSString *urlStr = ip;

```
if (![urlStr isEqualToString:@""])
{

    NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    if (!website)
    {
        NSString* messageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is not a valid URL",website];
        CCLog(LOG_ERROR, messageString);
        return;
    }

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)(urlStr), port, &readStream, &writeStream);

    //cast the CFStreams to NSStreams
    inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    //set the delegate
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    //schedule the stream on a run loop
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    //open the stream
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    if(readStream==NULL)
    {
        CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"readstream NULL");
    }

    if(writeStream == NULL)
    {
        CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"writeStream NULL");
    }

    [self startConnectionTimeoutTimer];
}
```

}

## pragma mark -

## pragma  getter methods

/*
 * getIP
 *
 * @return
 * Ip address to which socket is connected
 */
-(NSString *) getIP
{
    return ip;
}

/*
 * getPort
 *
 * @return
 * Port number to which socket is connected
 */
-(int) getPort
{
    return port;
}

## pragma mark-

## pragma Handle socket callbacks.

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
  {

  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [array addObject:stream];
  [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:eventCode]];

  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myStream:) withObject:array];
  }
- (void)myStream:(NSMutableArray*) array
  {
  NSNumber *number = [array objectAtIndex:1];
  int eventCode = [number intValue];

  switch(eventCode)
  {
      case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
      {
          CCLog(LOG_ERROR, @"In Command Socket NSStreamEventErrorOccurred");
          //[self disconnect];
          //[[ErrorDetails getInstance] reportError:NSStreamEventErrorOccurred];
          break;
      }

  ```
      //Read from stream
  case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
  {

      CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"In Command Socket NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");
      [self handleCommandPortDataReceived];
      break;
  }

      //Write to stream
  case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
  {
      @synchronized(self)
      {
          [requestReadyToProcess lock];
          while (isRequestReadyToProcess == false)
          {
              [requestReadyToProcess wait];
          }
          [requestReadyToProcess unlock];

          CCLog(LOG_INFO,@"In Command Socket NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable");

          @try
          {
              @synchronized(requestString)
              {
                  if(requestString != nil)
                  {
                      if(outputStream != nil)
                      {
                          int dataSent;

                          uint8_t* data = (uint8_t *)[requestString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                          responseString = @"";

                          //[requestReadyToProcess lock];
                          isRequestReadyToProcess = false;
                          //[requestReadyToProcess signal];
                          dataSent = [outputStream write:data maxLength:strlen((char*)data)];

                          if(dataSent != -1)
                          {
                              NSString* message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bytes written %d for request\n %@",dataSent, requestString];
                              CCLog(LOG_REQUEST, message);
                              requestString = nil;
                              isBytesReceived = false;
                              [bytesReceivedCondition lock];

                              while (isBytesReceived ==false)
                              {
                                  [bytesReceivedCondition wait];
                              }
                              [requestCompletedCondition lock];
                              isRequestCompleted = true;
                              [requestCompletedCondition signal];
                              [requestCompletedCondition unlock];
                              [bytesReceivedCondition unlock];
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"Command Socket : Request not sent (dataSent == -1)");
                              responseString = @"{ \"rval\": -104}";
                              CCLog(LOG_RESPONSE, responseString);

                              [self removeRequestFromQueue];
                          }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"in else :(outputStream != nil)");
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          @catch (NSException *e)
          {
              CCLog(LOG_WARNING, e.description);
          }
      }
      break;
  }
  case NSStreamEventNone:
  {
      CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"In Command Socket NSStreamEventNone");
      break;
  }
  case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
  {
      CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"In Command Socket NSStreamEventOpenCompleted");
      [self stopConnectionTimeoutTimer];
      break;
  }
  case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
  {
      CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"Command Socket NSStreamEventEndEncountered");

      [self disconnectWithNotification:YES];
      break;
  }
  ```

  }
  }

/*
 * execute
 *
 * @param
 * request :command to be sent over socket to camera
 *
 * @return
 * responce :response received from camera
 *
 */
-(NSString *) executeRequest :(NSString *)request
{
    CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"Command Socket Executing request");

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startRequestTimeoutTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

isRequestCompleted = false;
requestString = request;
responseString = @"";

[requestReadyToProcess lock];
isRequestReadyToProcess = true;
[requestReadyToProcess signal];
[requestReadyToProcess unlock];

[requestCompletedCondition lock];
while (isRequestCompleted ==false)
{
    [requestCompletedCondition wait];
}

CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"Command Socket Execute request : request completed");
[requestCompletedCondition unlock];
CCLog(LOG_RESPONSE, responseString);
return responseString;
```

}

## pragma mark-

## pragma Handle connection time out

// Call this when you initiate the connection
- (void)startConnectionTimeoutTimer
{
    [self stopConnectionTimeoutTimer]; // Or make sure any existing timer is stopped before this method is called

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 10.0; // Measured in seconds, is a double

self.connectionTimeoutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                                               target:self
                                                             selector:@selector(handleConnectionTimeout)
                                                             userInfo:nil
                                                              repeats:NO];
```

}

- (void)handleConnectionTimeout
  {
  responseString = @"{ \"rval\": -103}";
  CCLog(LOG_RESPONSE, responseString);

  [self removeRequestFromQueue];

  [self disconnectWithNotification:YES];
  [self stopConnectionTimeoutTimer];
  }

// Call this when you initiate the connection
- (void)startRequestTimeoutTimer
{
    [self stopRequestTimeoutTimer]; // Or make sure any existing timer is stopped before this method is called

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 20.0; // Measured in seconds, is a double

self.requestTimeoutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval
                                                               target:self
                                                             selector:@selector(handleRequestTimeout)
                                                             userInfo:nil
                                                              repeats:NO];
```

}

- (void)handleRequestTimeout
  {
  responseString = @"{ \"rval\": -103}";
  CCLog(LOG_RESPONSE, responseString);

  [self connectToCamera];
  [self stopRequestTimeoutTimer];
  [self removeRequestFromQueue];
  }

// Call this when you successfully connect
- (void)stopRequestTimeoutTimer
{
    if (requestTimeoutTimer)
    {
        [requestTimeoutTimer invalidate];
        requestTimeoutTimer = nil;
    }
}

-(void) disconnectWithNotification:(BOOL)showNotification
{
    CCLog(LOG_INFO, @"Socket Disconnected");
    [inputStream close];
    [inputStream setDelegate:nil];
    [inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                           forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    inputStream = nil;

```
[outputStream close];
[outputStream setDelegate:nil];
[outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                        forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
outputStream = nil;
[[CCCore getInstance] disconnectWithNotification:showNotification];
```

}

// Call this when you successfully connect
- (void)stopConnectionTimeoutTimer
{
    if (connectionTimeoutTimer)
    {
        [connectionTimeoutTimer invalidate];
        connectionTimeoutTimer = nil;
    }
    if (requestTimeoutTimer)
    {
        [requestTimeoutTimer invalidate];
        requestTimeoutTimer = nil;
    }
}

-(void) handleCommandPortDataReceived
{
    [mutex lock];
    [self stopRequestTimeoutTimer];
    @try
    {
        long size = 1024;
        uint8_t buf[size];
        unsigned int len = 0;

```
    do
    {
        // read input stream into buffer
        strcpy((char *)buf, "\0");
        len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:size];

        //NSLog(@"Size = %ld Len = %d, Buf = %s",size, len, (char *)buf);

        // Following code checks if we have received complete response by matching "{" and "}"
        // from input stream. We continue to form response string unless braces are matched.
        if (len > 0)
        {
            // Create nsdata from buffer
            NSMutableData *_data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];

            // create temporary string form nsdata
            NSString* currentString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            // check the occurances of { and } in current string
            int currentOpeningBraceCount = [[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"{"] count] - 1;
            int currentClosingBraceCount = [[currentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"}"] count] - 1;

            openBracesCount = (openBracesCount + currentOpeningBraceCount) - currentClosingBraceCount;
            responseString = [responseString stringByAppendingString:currentString];

            //                        NSLog(@"Total:%d currentOpen:%d currentClose:%d\n\n",openBracesCount, currentOpeningBraceCount, currentClosingBraceCount);
            //                        NSLog(@"Current String : %@\n\n",currentString);
            //                        NSLog(@"Final String : %@",finalString);
            //                        NSLog(@"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }
        else
            break;

    } while (openBracesCount != 0);


    NSRange range = [responseString rangeOfString:@"get_file_complete"];
    if(range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        //remove it from queue
        [bytesReceivedCondition lock];
        isBytesReceived = true;
        [bytesReceivedCondition signal];
        [bytesReceivedCondition unlock];
    }
    //responseString = @"";

}
@catch (NSException* e)
{
    [self connectToCamera];
}
[mutex unlock];
```

}

-(void) removeRequestFromQueue
{
    //remove it from queue
    requestString = nil;

```
[requestReadyToProcess lock];
isRequestReadyToProcess = false;
[requestReadyToProcess unlock];

[requestCompletedCondition lock];
isRequestCompleted = true;
[requestCompletedCondition signal];
[requestCompletedCondition unlock];
```

}

@end

Answer (score 0):

Which OS version are you trying this on??  I'm having the similar issue, in 10.7 and up it is all good, but on 10.6 and below I get the very same issue you are having I'm doing some debugging but so far have not come up with a good resolution yet.